# SQL: Filter out entries that appear more than once

Tags: sql

I'm new to SQL and hope to find some help here.
English is not my native language so if something seems unclear feel free to ask!

Like the topic name implies I want to filter out entries (Strings) from a table that exist more than once.

My code looks like this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT characterid, firstname, lastname, courseid
FROM Teaches
NATURAL JOIN Character
GROUP BY characterid, firstname, lastname, courseid
```

And it gives me this:

**Table**
[image]

The task is to filter out everyone who teaches more than 1 course. In this case it would be Snape and Quirrell. 
I tried it with counting

```
HAVING count(characterid) > 1
```

But that didn't work. I would be very happy if someone could help me and maybe explain why that count didn't work. Thank you in advance!

EDIT: If I say "filter" then I mean I want it as a result table. So that in the end I get a table with 2 rows with 
1) characterid Severus Snape 
2) characterid Quirinus Quirrell

Sorry for being so unclear. Also I only included the courseid in the SELECT statement to see who teaches more than one course more clearly. The final table should only have the three columns "characterid", "firstname" and "lastname"

EDIT2: Here is the structure of the data base. Maybe I'm completely wrong so it could be helpful to you guys: **Structure**

[image]

Comment: Which DBMS are you using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why that count didn't work? Because you group `courseid`, so it only count for **each** `courseid`, not count **all course for each** characterid

SO you should change it to

```
SELECT  
    characterid, firstname, lastname
FROM 
    Teaches
NATURAL JOIN 
    Character
GROUP BY 
    characterid, firstname, lastname
HAVING 
    COUNT(*) > 1;
```

And I suggest you use `INNER JOIN` instead of `NATURAL JOIN`. `NATURAL JOIN` is not standard, not clean, invisible to coder (Others can't know you want to join which columns, so it's not readable)

And according to your comment, I assume that you want to get all character that teaches more than 1 course in any year, any position.

So for your case you should use (if you want to get in any school then delete t.schoolid in the subquery):

```
SELECT
    characterid, firstname, lastname
FROM
    (
    SELECT DISTINCT
        c.characterid, c.firstname, c.lastname, t.courseid, t.schoolid
    FROM 
        Teaches t
    INNER JOIN 
        Character c
    ON
        t.characterid = c.characterid
    )
GROUP BY 
    characterid, firstname, lastname
HAVING 
    COUNT(*) > 1;
```

Comment: Hello! Thanks for your quick feedback and tips. I tried it like you suggested and the result is this [Table2](http://i.imgur.com/9yRyE9d.png). It's the same result that I got when I grouped it with courseid :( To be sure I also uploaded it as a solution on our practice server and the feedback was negative

Comment: I included the structure in my first post. Maybe I started completely wrong [structure](http://i.stack.imgur.com/R3LF6.png)

Comment: @djaru It seems like problem is in your table. Could you run this query and show the result?: `SELECT * FROM teaches t INNER JOIN character c ON t.characterid = c.characterid WHERE c.characterid = 5;` According to your reply, this query must return more than 1 rows.

Comment: @djaru For your case, you should use the second query in my edited answer